# calculate cumulative probability from binomial logit output in R

Tags: r, probability

I have a fitted binomial logit model and want to calculate the cumulative probability of experiencing an event <= some value of a covariate.

For example, If I have a fitted model that predicts and outcome based on a continuous distance range (0-8.5 km) I might want to find out the cumulative probability for distance <= to 4.5 km.

I have vectors of estimated probabilities and the associated distances as below

```
dat <- structure(list(km = c(0, 0.447368421052632, 0.894736842105263, 
1.34210526315789, 1.78947368421053, 2.23684210526316, 2.68421052631579, 
3.13157894736842, 3.57894736842105, 4.02631578947368, 4.47368421052632, 
4.92105263157895, 5.36842105263158, 5.81578947368421, 6.26315789473684, 
6.71052631578947, 7.15789473684211, 7.60526315789474, 8.05263157894737, 
8.5), prob = c(0.99010519543441, 0.985413663823809, 0.97854588563623, 
0.968547716962174, 0.954108659036907, 0.933496091194704, 0.904551377544634, 
0.864833064332603, 0.81202174997839, 0.744668375529677, 0.663191827576796, 
0.570704402277059, 0.47300143764816, 0.377323442817887, 0.290336664745317, 
0.216433162546689, 0.157174982015906, 0.111825887625402, 0.0783449309507567, 
0.054275681518511)), .Names = c("km", "prob"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I ultimately want to say is "x% of observations within x distance are predicted to experience an event". Is this the right way to go about that?

Also is there an easy way to calculate at which distance (from 0 - whatever) encompasses the 50% cumulative probability.

Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some way to extract this from your model, but if you were doing it from scratch I would try to fit your data to a distribution, then extract your relevant data points.

First define an error function:

```
rmse <- function(x,y) sqrt(sum((x-y)^2)/length(x)) # or some other error fxn
```

Now let's say your data sort of looks like a gamma distribution, so try:

```
gdf <- function(x, d=dat$km) pgamma(d,shape=x[1], scale=x[2])
```

So your function to optimize will be the error function of your data and the fit distribution:

```
error_fxn <- function(x) rmse(rev(dat$prob),gdf(x)) # rev data to make ascending
```

Now optimize this function to get your parameters for the distribution of interest:

```
rr <- optim(c(1,1),error_fxn)
```

And let's see how good the fit is (just ok...);

```
rr
# $par
# [1] 3.108392 1.112584

# $value
# [1] 0.0333369

# $counts
# function gradient 
     119       NA 

# $convergence
# [1] 0

# $message
# NULL
```

Or graphicaly:

```
with(dat,plot(km,prob,xlim=c(10,0)))
with(dat,lines(rev(km),pgamma(km,shape=rr$par[1], scale=rr$par[2]),col='red'))
```

[image]

Take a look at the values for the CDF:

```
kms <- seq(0,8.5,0.5)
data.frame(dist = kms, cdf = pgamma(kms,shape=rr$par[1], scale=rr$par[2]))

#       dist         cdf
#    1   0.0 0.000000000
#    2   0.5 0.008634055
#    3   1.0 0.053615340
#    4   1.5 0.137291689
#    5   2.0 0.245961242
#    6   2.5 0.363956061
#    7   3.0 0.479070721
#    8   3.5 0.583659363
#    9   4.0 0.673982194
#    10  4.5 0.749075757
#    11  5.0 0.809691054
#    12  5.5 0.857478086
#    13  6.0 0.894431622
#    14  6.5 0.922551998
#    15  7.0 0.943661710
#    16  7.5 0.959325076
#    17  8.0 0.970830577
#    18  8.5 0.979207658
```

And to answer your final question, get the distance at 50% of the CDF:

```
qgamma(0.5,shape=rr$par[1], scale=rr$par[2])
# [1] 3.095395
```

Comment: thanks for putting this together. I have been mulling this over for most of the day and seem to keep coming back to simple means. The predicted probabilities are calculated at even breaks along the x axis (km). In my mind it makes sense to simply average the probabilities over any range I am interested in making inference about. Across the entire range 0-8.5 km the average probability is 0.60. So if the study subjects are evenly spread across the landscape then, 60% between 0 and 8.5 km are predicted to experience an event. Do you see a problem in this?